# How to target the last child in each of a series of divs?

Tags: html, css, sass, nested, css-selectors

I'm making an EJS-based site with Express on the back end. I have a page which is dynamically populated. I'm trying to write scss which targets the last `img.collab-img` element in each `div.year-box`

The html looks a bit like this, once it's loaded in the browser ...

```
<div class="content-box">

      <div class="year-box">
      
        <p>2021</p>
        <p>...</p>

                <a>
                    <div class="credits credits-flex">
                      <span class="no-text-decoration">
                        ...
                      </span>
                        <span class="link-arrow">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;→
                        </span>
                    </div>
                      <img class="collab-img" src="" alt="">
                </a>
                </br> 
                <a>
                    <div class="credits credits-flex">
                      <span class="no-text-decoration">
                        ...
                      </span>
                        <span class="link-arrow">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;→
                        </span>
                    </div>
                      <img class="collab-img" src="" alt="">
                  </a>

              </br>
           
      </div>

      <div class="year-box">
      
        <p>2020</p>
        <p>...</p>

                <a>
                    <div class="credits credits-flex">
                      <span class="no-text-decoration">
                        ...
                      </span>
                        <span class="link-arrow">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;→
                        </span>
                    </div>
                      <img class="collab-img" src="" alt="">
                  </a>
                  </br>
                 <a>
                    <div class="credits credits-flex">
                      <span class="no-text-decoration">
                        ...
                      </span>
                        <span class="link-arrow">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;→
                        </span>
                    </div>
                      <img class="collab-img" src="" alt="">
                  </a>
                  </br>
                  <a>
                    <div class="credits credits-flex">
                      <span class="no-text-decoration">
                        ...
                      </span>
                        <span class="link-arrow">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;→
                        </span>
                    </div>
                      <img class="collab-img" src="" alt="">
                  </a>

              </br>
           
      </div>
</div>
```

I tried

```
.year-box {
    img:last-of-type {
       border: 1px solid black;
    }
  }
```

but it applied to style to all of the images, not only the last one in each year-box.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. The selector which worked was...

```
.year-box a:last-of-type img { }
```